# Parameter Pack Sorting (Or Equivalent Behavior)

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20

I want:

```
template<class ... T>
auto foo()
{
  // ✨ magic ✨
}
```

Such that:

```
(foo<int, char, bool>() == foo<char, int, bool>()) // True
(foo<int>() == foo<char>()) // False
```

In other words, I want foo to return a unique id for the *combination* of types passed to it rather than the *permutation* of types passed to it.

My first idea was that there might be some way to sort the parameter pack at compile time, though I'm not sure how exactly that would work.

My current solution is this:

```
// Precondition: Client must pass the parameters in alphabetical order to ensure the same result each time
template<class ... T>
std::type_index foo()
{
  return std::make_type_index(typeid(std::tuple<T ... >));
}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't work if the client is using type aliases. For example:

```
using my_type = char;
(foo<bool, int, my_type>() == foo<bool, char, int>()) // False
```

One idea I had is to assign a new prime number as an id for every new type that the function handles. Then I could assign a unique id for a particular combination of types by multiplying their prime number ids together. For example:

```
id of int = 2
id of bool = 3
id of char = 5
id of <int, bool, char> = 2 * 3 * 5 = 30
id of <bool, int, char> = 3 * 2 * 5 = 30
```

Only problem is how I'm going to assign unique prime number ids to each type without incurring a runtime penalty.

Comment: And you want this all to be constexpr too? Because as stated you can just return `std::set<std::type_index>{typeid(T)...}`

Comment: As far as I know `std::type_index` is the only way to sort arbitrary types, and it isn't `constexpr`. If the set of possible types is limited, you can try putting them all in a `std::tuple` then sort the types according to their position in that tuple.

Comment: You can solve this by iterating over the types of the one operand and removing that type from the right hand operand's set of types until you either fail to find a type (not equal),  are left with an non-empty set (not equal) or left with an empty set of types (equal).

Comment: Preferably. I can already think of a decent runtime version which uses an `std::map<std::type_index, std::size_t>` to either look up or generate the unique prime number ids of each type. But theoretically, you can hard code the prime number id of each type that you use, so then there would be no runtime penalty.

Comment: @康桓瑋 As in, the cardinality of two typelists? No, they are not guaranteed to be equal. I could have `foo<type1>()` and foo<type2, type3>()` and I would expect them to return unique values no matter what types are chosen.

Answer (score 5):

Using Boost.Hana:

```
#include <boost/hana/set.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/type.hpp>

template<typename... T>
constexpr auto foo() {
    return boost::hana::make_set(boost::hana::type_c<T>...);
}

using my_type = char;
static_assert(foo<bool, int, my_type>() == foo<bool, char, int>());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the gcc /clang's extension `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (`__FUNCSIG__` in msvc) as the identifier of each type and save them into `std::array`, then sort it to get the unique combination of type list.

But since `std::arrays` of different sizes cannot be compared with each other, we also need create a new type (`unique_id`) to wrap the sorted array and overload its `operator==`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

template <class T>
constexpr std::string_view id() {
#ifdef __GNUC__
  return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
  return __FUNCSIG__;
#endif
}

template<std::size_t N>
class unique_id {
  std::array<std::string_view, N> value;
 public:
  constexpr unique_id(const std::array<std::string_view, N>& value) : value(value) { }
  template<std::size_t M>
  constexpr bool operator==(const unique_id<M>& other) const {
    if constexpr (N == M) return value == other.value;
    else return false;
  }
};

template<class... Ts>
constexpr auto foo() {
  std::array<std::string_view, sizeof...(Ts)> names{id<Ts>()...};
  std::ranges::sort(names);
  return unique_id(names);
}

static_assert(foo<int, char, bool>() == foo<char, int, bool>());
static_assert(foo<int>() != foo<char>());
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/1a1qWG4Kv)

Answer (score 2):

With Boost.Mp11:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr std::string_view type_name() {
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; // close enough
}

template <typename T, typename U>
using type_less = mp_bool<type_name<T>() < type_name<U>()>;

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto foo() {
    return type_name<mp_sort<mp_list<Ts...>, type_less>>();
}

static_assert(foo<int, char>() == foo<char, int>());
```

Comment: clang's `[]{}` has additional signatures so `foo<decltype([]{})>()! = foo<decltype([]{})>()`, but gcc does [not](https://godbolt.org/z/9qeMqGe6d).

Comment: such a shame that typeid does not play nicely with constexpr, with that and constexpr string and vector I think there could be a almost "runtime code" solution, although I presume one would need to dump the sorted names to 2D std::array.